# How to Solve this Integral $\int_{\mid x\mid =r} xdz$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, line-integrals

This is NOT a duplicate question.

I need some help computing the integral

$\int_{\mid z\mid =r} xdz$

But I really want to use the fact that

$x=\frac{1}{2}(z + \frac {r^{2}}{{z}})$ when the circle is oriented counter-clockwise in the integral.

Should I just plug that into the integral?
I have seen the similar question to this and understand how to use parameters to get that the integral equals $r^{2}i\frac{\pi}{2}$.  However, I am interested in using the fact mentioned above, which requires a different method than the solutions already discussed on this site, so it is not a duplicate.
How would I go about this?

Comment: By $x$ do you mean the real part of $z$???

Comment: Yes that is what I mean

Comment: The problem I am having is that if $x$ is the real part of $z$ and $|z|=r$, we have $x=\frac{1}{2}\left(z + \frac{r^2}{z}\right)$.

Comment: No it's not a duplicate. Please read what I'm asking before you jump to that.

Comment: Please help. This question is not a duplicate

Comment: Note that you should have ${1 \over 2} (z + {r^2 \over z})$. You have $|z|$ in your question.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I've fixed that.

Comment: Why is this question ignored??

Comment: Circle ? What circle ? All I see is two verticals.

Comment: Do you know how to compute $\int_\gamma {dz \over z}$?

Comment: I presume by $|x|=r$ you mean $|z|=r$?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for not seeing that typo earlier. You are correct

Answer (score 0):

$|x|=r$ is $x=-r\lor x=r$ and the integral can be translated to

$$\int_{|x|=r}x\,dz=-\int_{z=-r-i\infty}^{-r+i\infty}r\,dz+\int_{z=r-i\infty}^{r+i\infty}r\,dz,$$ assuming "counterclockwise traversal".

I guess that this can be said to equal zero in the Cauchy sense.

---

Assuming a typo in the problem statement,

$$\int_{|\color{red}z|=r}x\,dz=\int_{t=0}^{2\pi}r\cos(t)\,d(re^{it})=r^2\int_{t=0}^{2\pi}\cos(t)ie^{it}dt=\\r^2\int_{t=0}^{2\pi}(i\cos^2(t)-\cos(t)\sin(t))\,dt=i\pi r^2$$
by the average values of $\cos^2(t)$ and $\cos(t)\sin(t)$. The sign is positive for a counterclockwise traversal.

Comment: I would presume the OP meant $|z|=r$ for want of better notation.

Comment: @copper.hat: I raised that issue in a comment, and in the meanwhile showed that the current problem statement is absurd.

Answer (score -1):

The solution depends on the tools you have. Using this fact makes me suspect that you can use the residue theorem:

$\int_{|z|=r} \Re z dz = {1\over2}\int (z+r^2/z) dz = {1\over2}(\int z dz + r^2\int z^{-1} dz) = {1\over2}(0+r^22\pi i)$

To just go ahead and just plug it into the integral by using $\Re z = {z + r^2/z\over2}$ doesn't make much sense:

$\int\Re z dz = \int{z + r^2/z\over2}dz = \int_0^{2\pi}  {re^{i\varphi}+r^2/(re^{i\varphi})\over2}ire^{i\varphi}d\varphi = \int_0^{2\pi}r{e^{i\varphi}+e^{-i\varphi}\over2}ire^{i\varphi}d\varphi = \int_0^{2\pi}r\cos(\varphi) ire^{i\varphi}d\varphi$

that is a complicated way to arrive at the same integral as if we didn't use that fact and just went ahead and evaluated the integral (and instead using the fact that $\Re re^{i\varphi} = r\cos\varphi$):

$\int\Re z dz = \int_0^{2\pi} r\cos(\varphi) ire^{i\varphi}d\varphi$

Comment: The last integral is $0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, I missed the $\gamma'$ term, that's now corrected. The point was that you arrive at the same integral if you just plug in $\Re z={z+r^2/z\over2}$ as if you don't (except it's more work).

Comment: It would be nice if whoever voted down this explained why so I can improve the answer if there's still a problem.